# Pushing onto the navigation stack with (or without) the navigation controller's bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

I have created a view controller that needs to be able to use its own navigation bar but still be contained in the navigation stack. I have already solved this by simply hiding the `UINavigationController`'s navigation bar, and then adding in a fake navigation bar into each view controller. With this I'm getting the following look every time I push a view controller. [image: This is the look for pushing/popping I'm getting for every view controller. I only need this look in one specific view controller.]

What I want is that some pushes result in using the navigation bar of the incoming view controller (image 1), and then other pushes result in this [image: Regular navigation controller push]

Comment: So what is the issue or question ?

Comment: I need to be able to push onto the navigation stack such that only some view controllers use the navigation bar from the navigation controller. Just look at the pictures. Picture 1 the incoming VC brings its own navigation bar while in picture 2 the VC simply uses the navigation controller's bar like normal. How can I selectively choose when to use the navigation controller's bar and when to use the custom bar in the incoming VC?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to phrase it is, I want some view controllers to totally replace the entire view (besides the tab bar) and some to push regularly using the navigation controller's bar.

Answer (score 0):

On which viewController you need to use custom Navigation bar on that viewcontroller, hide navigationbar in `viewWillAppear` and show again in `viewDidDisappear`. So, it will be hidden for particular that viewcontroller. And show your custom navigationbar in that viewcontroller from `viewDidload`

Comment: I believe I have already tried that and I got a very unwelcome animation where the bar from the navigation controller continued to move as if it was just right under the new view controller. I'll try it again and post a GIF or picture of what is wrong with this solution if I get the same result. If you open the Twitter app on your phone you'll see the navigation controller's bar stays put even when pushing to a view controller that doesn't use the navigation controller's bar.